# AsEnumerable() vs. "as IEnumerable<T>"

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

What is the difference between

```
(db.Records as IEnumerable<Record>).Where(...)
```

and

```
(db.Records.AsEnumerable()).Where(...).
```

Is `AsEnumerable()` a shortcut for `source as IEnumerable<T>` only?

I've read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.90).aspx, but did't find any info about it.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ee4ab000402fbeb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that you can call `AsEnumerable` on an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is an anonymous type, and you couldn't perform such a cast on such a sequence, since you can't type out the name of a type that has no name.  This ability of `AsEnumerable` to infer the generic argument is the reason for it to exist.

(It's also arguably cleaner syntax, but outside of anonymous types that's not a functional difference, merely a personal preference.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant sections on that article.

First,

> The AsEnumerable(IEnumerable) method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements IEnumerable to IEnumerable itself.

And second,

> If remote execution is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local method, the AsEnumerable method can be used to hide the custom methods and instead make the standard query operators available.

In other words, yes, it looks like a shortcut. However, it is meant to enforce in memory operations of `Where` and other `IEnumerable<T>` methods versus the actual implementations of the underlying type.

Comment: There are slight differences between the 2. `as` is like a cast operation, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) while `AsEnumerable()` returns the object as `Enumerable<T>` through a method.

Comment: @JohnOdom And how are those two things different?  You say that there is a difference, but don't say *what it is*.

Comment: @JohnOdom to the effects, it is the same thing with a different syntax. The method can be implemented with just `return this as IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @rae1 Actually, since the return type of the method is `IEnumerable<T>` the implementation actually is just `return source;`.  It is implicitly converted to match the return type of the method.  You can see this in [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ee4ab000402fbeb)